# Github - gitignore folder doesn't exclude all directory files

Tags: gitignore, github-desktop

I'm using Github Desktop on Windows 10. I have a .gitignore file with which I'd like to ignore *everything* in the directory, including all subdirectories.

What's frustrating is that *most* files are excluded, but I'm still getting a few random files that I cannot seem to ignore.

I have a directory, say, `My Dir/Sub-dir`, I want to ignore. I also want to ignore all files of extension, say, `*.swf`. Thus, I write this `.gitignore` file:

```
My Dir/Sub-dir

*.swf
```

But, when I go back to Github Desktop, I still get two files similar to the following in the list:

```
My Dir/Sub-dir/anotherdir/randomfile.xml
My Dir/Sub-dir/animation.swf
```

What's going on? Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Other alternative `.gitignore`s I've tried are:

```
My*Dir/Sub-dir
*.swf
```

```
My\ Dir/Sub-dir
*.swf
```

```
My Dir/Sub-dir/
*.swf
```

```
/My Dir/Sub-dir
*.swf
```

**EDIT:**

So, I've tried the `git rm --cached <file>` command on my files, and it worked - until one of the files changes again. Github Desktop then *once again* says they need to be updated.

p.s. It may be that they somehow got indexed in the master branch, as I'm currently in a different branch. Would this cause it? And, if so, how would I eliminate these files from all branches?

Answer (score 1):

To ignore all trees under specific directories, append the trailing slash to the directory:

```
# Ignore directory at all levels, even if the directory is nested under other directories
My Dir/Sub-dir/
# Ignore the directory only if it exists at the root of your repository
/My Dir/Sub-dir/
# Ignore the sub-directory, no matter where it appears within your repository
Sub-dir/
# Ignore all swf files
*.swf
```

If you are continuing to experience difficulties, your problem may be that the files you wish to ignore are already indexed by git (via the `git add` command). If the files are not committed yet, you can remove them from the index with `git reset -- 'My Dir/Sub-dir/'`. If your files have been committed, you can remove them from the index with `git rm --cached <file>`.

Comment: That did it! It just got cached.
So, having found my git install from GitHub Desktop (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565238/where-does-github-desktop-install-command-line-version-of-git#answer-46966548) I was able to remove it from the index.

Comment: Sorry, I *thought* it worked.. Check out my second edit. Maybe you'll have an idea.

Comment: @Codesmith after removing it from the index (via `git rm --cached`) did you commit the removal?

Comment: To clarify, if there is a file committed to the repo that you want to remove (without removing your local copy) you can use `git rm --cached` to stage the deletion of that file from the repo. You will still need to commit that change in order for the file to actually get deleted from the repo, and until this commit is made you may see your env (GitHub Desktop) re-add it automatically when changes are made. On other hand, if the file isn't committed yet then `git reset -- <file>` will do the trick.

Comment: Also just to add as a note to clarify the answer above, `.gitignore` only *prevents* **non-indexed** files from being added to the repo -- it won't do anything to files that are already indexed.

Comment: Thanks @MikeHill, good to know that about `.gitignore`. So, what's odd is `git rm --cached` appears to work fine (showing the `filename [-]`) *until* I commit it and it changes again, when it thus re-appears as a 'changed' file. Do note, I likely committed these files to the master branch, and I'm currently on a different branch. Could that cause the issue?

Comment: As long as you don't switch from your current branch then that should be fine. Have you checked the changes in the commit (`git show` after the commit) to ensure that the removal was actually committed? And did you also add matching patterns to your `.gitignore`? The files will keep getting re-added if a suitable pattern does not exist there. You will want to commit the `.gitignore` changes for the future, too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the whitespace could be a problem. Try

```
My\ Dir/Sub-dir
```

or

```
My*Dir/Sub-dir
```

This could be a good reference [.gitignore entire directory with whitespace in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310179/gitignore-entire-directory-with-whitespace-in-name)

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. And I had found that suggestion online and tried it. Unfortunately, it still didn't work... :-/ I'll edit my question.